# Questions about creating a new tag

Tags: support, tags

I was looking at the new questions when I noticed [this question](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/questions/31486/awkward-conversations-in-elevators-lifts-how-to-avoid) which had three tags including [elevator](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/elevator) and [lift](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/lift) which seemed to be proposed by the person who asked the question. Since these did not seem like helpful tags I retagged the questions and removed the offending tags. I then went to look the other questions they just asked and saw that they also proposed a [greeting](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/greeting) tag.

This is what stumped me, we don't have a greeting tag, it seems a little bit localized but there are a number of questions about greeting others. The tag feels useless without all the old questions not allowing it for that reason would would kind of defeat the point of making a new tag at all!

So when is it appropriate to make a new tag and if you do, should you go an retag all the old posts to which it applies?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The best thing you can do when making a new tag is:

1. Creating a tag wiki and tag excerpt to explain how it is used
2. Retag any obvious questions that fall in to it

If a tag exists, and is clear to new users, it will be used in the future. If there is only one question with that tag, it may be auto-deleted in the future. So definitely try to retag a couple questions, if for no other reason than if you can't find other questions to retag, it may not be an ideal tag to use right now.